# What's the best way to run unit tests against an ASP.NET REST Web API server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, nunit, iis-express, web-api-testing

We have an ASP.NET Web API server app that provides a REST API.

What I want is pretty simple. That when our unit tests run, and I prefer NUnit but can do the Microsoft test framework, that it would fire up the server app. And I then have unit tests written that make REST calls and assert the returned response.

Which leaves the questions:

1. Is there a way when the tests start, to first get our server web app up and running on IIS Express. And not start the tests until it is running and available.
2. Is there a way to either hard-code the port for the web app on IIS Express or to get the port for the unit tests?
3. How do I get IIS Express to end my web app and then exit?
4. To do this, do I then need all the tests in one suite so I'm not starting & stopping multiple instances of our web app?

Comment: The API client should be mocked. What you're talking about is integration testing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You described an integration test in asp.net core and there is good documentation for that starting with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

You need to basically setup a host inside your IntegrationTests solution using [Generic host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and then all points 1-4 are covered

Comment: This is very helpful. By any chance are you aware of a very simple sample project that does this? Preferably for a Web API app?

Comment: @DavidThielen Maybe not the simplest of the simple, but still quite readable with official guideline: [github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/test/integration-tests/samples/3.x/IntegrationTestsSample/tests/RazorPagesProject.Tests) and [guideline](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/test/integration-tests.md)